Measure Common Mode Choke Impedance on VNA
I am seeking clarity on measuring a common mode impedance and attenuation on an HF 1:1 common mode choke. The chokes are broadband, typically 2 to 30 MHz, wound on toroid cores with type 31 and 43 ferrite material. They are wound with Coax cable or bifilar wires to maintain a 50-ohm transmission line impedance.
I have seen three test methods (see below) used to measure choking impedance on a VNA, and each technique claims to be correct. I think only one conductor needs measuring—for example, the shield of the coax. I am not sure if both conductors should be measured. If they do, would I use the resistors or not?
Thanks for any guidance.


In my opinion, the last scheme is the right one.
The first one measures the leakage inductance, i.e. the differential mode. I don't understand the middle one: the resistors will generate losses that are not those of the common-mode choke.
I suggest you make a comparison between :

Your VNA measurement
The manufacturer's datasheet
A simulator

Take this common-mode choke, for example 744821039 https://www.we-online.com/components/products/datasheet/744821039.pdf

Here's a simulation with your latest schematic

You'll notice that the simulation model doesn't show all the parasitic resonances of the real choke. This is one of the limitations of the simulation, but we're close enough to make comparisons.

I think the first one can work in principle, but it's misrepresented by its source. The actual method is measuring two terminals at a time using the VNA, while terminating unused ones with standard RF loads to the reference plane of the text fixture. Finally you put them together, thus obtaining the 4-port S-parameters (which fully characterizes the DUT).

I wanted to return and share my solution. I aim to construct a VNA Test Jig for measuring HF and VHF common mode chokes. This Test Jig will be a VNA test plane equipped with an integrated calibration standard: Short, Open, Load, and Thru. Utilizing this jig will remove any stray capacitance and inductance that could obscure the performance of the Device Under Test (DUT).
My post intended to ascertain whether to utilize the shield, center conductor, or both in a coaxial cable for measuring common attenuation and impedance. Following some investigation, I discovered that either the shield or both could be used. Consequently, I have designed the circuit below. The test jig will be constructed on a double-sided PCB featuring an extensive ground plane, akin to the test jig illustrated below.


